# Change variable with string instead of just accessing it

Tags: javascript

I can access a variable easily:

```
function accessVariable(accessFunction, variable) {
    var namespaces = accessFunction.split(".");
    for (var b = 0; b < namespaces.length; b++) {
        if (namespaces[b] != "") {
            try {
                variable = variable[namespaces[b]];
            } catch {
                variable = undefined;
            };
        };
        return variable;
    };
```

But updating this gotten variable is something that I don't know how to do.

Comment: Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: @Spectric He means the nested object element that's identified by the `accessFunction` string.

Comment: So I am trying to update the document variable with a string the user provides. So I run something like accessVariable(".body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'", document); And am trying to make the document change to red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest if you use a separate function to update. This can take the new value as another argument.

Then you stop the iteration before the last item in `namespace`, and use that as the index to assign to.

```js
function updateVariable(accessFunction, variable, value) {
  var namespaces = accessFunction.split(".");
  for (var b = 0; b < namespaces.length - 1; b++) {
    if (namespaces[b] != "") {
      try {
        variable = variable[namespaces[b]];
      } catch {
        variable = undefined;
      }
    }
  }
  if (variable) {
    variable[namespaces.pop()] = value;
  }
}

let obj = {a: {b:[{c: 10}]}};
updateVariable('a.b.0.c', obj, 20);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I've tried this like this but it just changes the local variable stored in the variable parameter and not the real underlying variable. Like if I wanted to change document.body.backgroundColor = red; This would just give me a variable that contains red and not change the backgroundColor

Comment: I've added an example showing how to use it.

Comment: Turns out I tried changing background color to "red" instead of a string red and it messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Define a single global-scoped variable, and put your variables there.

```
var Glob = {}; // globally scoped object

function changeVar(){
    Glob.variable1 = 'value1';
}

function SeeVar(){
    alert(Glob.variable1); // shows 'value1'
}
```